# Making prediction whether user will be able to solve a thing or not

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, weka, naivebayes

I have 3 datasets in csv
problem.csv with attributes:

1. id
2. level
3. accuracy
4. solved_count
5. error_count
6. tag1
7. tag2
8. tag3
9. tag4
10. tag5

Submission.csv with attibutes:

- user_id
- problem_id
- solved_status

user.csv with

- user_id
- solved_count
- attempts

I want to now predict on a test dataset that whether user will be able to solve a problem or not.

I was thinking of applying Naive Bayes Classification. But i don't know how to approach this problem. I suppose i have to make a common dataset in arff for use with Weka or sckit learn. Give me some idea of how i can approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a weka, you should join all data sets together. 
To get one data set with attributes as follows:

- user_id
- id
- level
- accuracy
- solved_count
- error_count
- tag1
- tag2
- tag3
- tag4
- tag5
- solved_count
- attempts
- solved_status (this will be your class)

After this work you have to load the data set to weka explorer or in java code.
You have to build a classifier based on your data set.
Then you can predict your new instance where the solved_status will be empty.

Comment: You can different classifier. The most common are j48, random forest, naive bayes, knn, svn. Check all of them and take the one which get best results.